# OO language - no article?

Tags: grammar, articles

> However, we haven't gone through the details of **OO language** in PHP.

A friend of mine, who is a native English speaker, says that this sentence sounds okay to him - you don't need an article. Nevertheless you do say THE English language or THE Spanish language in English. Why is it not the case here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'OO' in that context stands for 'object-oriented'.

> However, we haven't gone through the details of object-oriented language in PHP.

Object-oriented programming/scripting/coding (be it PHP or any other language) is a particular style of coding, and is not a separate language in itself. 'English' and 'Spanish' obviously are distinct languages. We therefore use the definite article when referring to the language that is English, as we're referring to a discrete entity. So, as per your example:

> However, we haven't gone through the details of the English language in business settings.

We would not use a definite article when talking about a particular style or usage of English, and would instead say:

> However, we haven't gone through the details of business language in English.

Just like object-oriented PHP, 'business language' in English is nebulous and indefinite — it is not a specific language. Hence, no definite article.

Comment: Not worth writing my own answer for it, but you could maybe add that with _any_ non-definite adjective in front of _language_, no definite article is used: we talked about _formal language_, we talked about _sign language_. But if the adjective defines _one_ language, the definite article is used: we talked about the _Maori language_, _we talked about the _recently discovered_ language that the author mentioned in his article.